# How can I make localStorage data persistent across pages?

Tags: jquery, json, local-storage

I'm building a sticky notes page. I want to save the created notes. The data is being saved with `localStorage()`, which make the data persistent on page reload, but not when a surfing to other pages. How can I make make the notes still being saved, when returning from another page?

```
   var notes, count = 0;

function saveNotes() {
    var notesArray = [];
    notes.find("li > div").each(function (i, e) {
        var title = $(e).find("input.note-title");
        var content = $(e).find("textarea.note-content");

        notesArray.push({ Index: i, Title: title.val(), Content: content.val() });
    });

    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(notesArray);

    localStorage.setItem("notes", jsonStr);
}

function addNoteEvent(noteElement) {
    var div = noteElement.children("div");
    var closeIcon = div.find("i");

    div.focus(function () {
        closeIcon.removeClass("hidden");
    });

    div.hover(function () {
        closeIcon.removeClass("hidden");
    }, function () {
        closeIcon.addClass("hidden");
        saveNotes();
    }) 
}

function addNewNote(className, title, content) {

    notes.append("<li><div class='col-md-3 portfolio-item img'>" + 
                    "<input class='note-title' placeholder='Untitled'/>" + 
                    "<i class='fa fa-trash-o hidden'></i>" +
                    "<textarea class='note-content' placeholder='Your content here'/>" +  
                "</div></li>");

    var newNote = notes.find("li:last");
    newNote.find("i").click(function () {
        newNote.remove();
        saveNotes();
    });

    addNoteEvent(newNote);


    if (title) {
        newNote.find("input.note-title").val(title);
    }
    if (content) {
        newNote.find("textarea.note-content").val(content);
    }
    saveNotes();
}

function loadNotes() {
    var storedNotes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if (storedNotes) {
        var notesArray = JSON.parse(storedNotes);
        count = notesArray.length;

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var storedNote = notesArray[i];
            addNewNote(storedNote.Class, storedNote.Title, storedNote.Content);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    notes = $("#notities .container > .row");

    loadNotes();
    $(".btnNew").click(function () {
        addNewNote();
    });

    if (count === 0) {
        $(".btnNew").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you get when you try to access the localStorage data from another page?

Comment: Are you calling `saveNotes()` on every page? The data should persist unless you've overwriting it or clearing `localStorage` entirely. Perhaps you need to rethink the naming convention of your `setItem` key.

Comment: Only the page that stored the data can access it. So by surfing to other pages, by definition, you can's access local storage. "Returning" to the same page should work, though.

Comment: @G.Stoynev: No, `localStorage` is scoped to the Origin, not the page.  (You might be thinking of `sessionStorage`, which is scoped to the page.)

Comment: @josh3736, you're absolutely right - protocol-domain-port combination. I am living in a SPAs world :-)

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` is persistent across pages *in the same domain*.  The normal same-origin rules are applied to [DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), so as long as your pages are on the same domain, the data will be accessible.

Comment: My data is only saved on page reload, when I go to another page in the same domain and return the notes(data) are gone

Comment: That's not correct behavior.  The data should remain.  Are you sure the other page isn't accidentally clearing local storage or overwriting the `notes` key?

Comment: Nothing in that seems amiss.  I was asking if the page you navigate *to* does anything with local storage.  Open Chrome's developer tools, go to the Resources panel, and select your domain under Local Storage.  You can then watch in real time as items are added/removed/modified.  This will help you see exactly when your data is disappearing.